# Unload javascript file when modal dialog is closed

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-5

I have a modal dialog that has been styled to show along the right hand side of the customers browser.  Depending on the icon they click in a nav bar (here is an example) ...

```
<a class="nav-link right-menu" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#rightSubMenu" data-id="admin-menu">
    <i class="fas fa-users-crown"></i>
</a>
```

An ajax call is made and an HTML fragment is loaded in to the modal-body via an additional class named .right-sub-menu-content.  Here is the ajax call ...

```
$('.right-menu').click( function() {
    var requestedMenu = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "//" + $(location).attr('hostname') + "/modules/",
        data: {
            'module': requestedMenu
        },
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.right-sub-menu-content').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I am also loading a js file to handle buttons, additional select menu updates, etc.  Its loaded using a standard <script src="something.js"></script> tag as part of the HTML fragment.

My problem -- In one particular fragment I load a dashboard to provide my admins server status updates.  It refreshes several DIVs once every 5 minutes via ajax by using a setInterval.

I found out that after closing the modal dialog, that setInterval continues to run, even though I destroy the contents of the modal-body, which I thought would include the script that was loaded as part of the fragment, using the following in the main.js file ...

```
$('.modal.right').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $('.right-sub-menu-content').html('');
});
```

So my question is ... since I'm reusing the modal dialog for other HTML fragments which include their own JS files, how can I unload the js file completely when the modal is closed?

Thank you all for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stop the `setInterval` function with `clearInterval` maybe this will work for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.  Yes I can definitely kill it using clearInterval.  However, my concern is that other portions of these JS files that are loaded with their respective HTML fragments are also remaining in memory and could wreak havoc on other fragments when they get loaded in to the modal.  I'm hoping there is a way to unload these JS files when they are no longer needed.